# Azure Storage emulator with Nodejs createQueueService error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm receiving the following error when I try connecting to the emulated storage queue service:

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature.
>
> Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

This is the approach I'm using to connect to the azure storage:

```
    var storageAccount = 'devstoreaccount1'
    var accessKey= 'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=='
    var azure = require('azure-storage');
    var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService(storageAccount,accessKey);

    queueSvc.createMessage('myqueue', "Hello world!", function(error, results, response){
      if(!error){
        // Message inserted
      }
    });
```

I also tryed using the following connection strings, without success:

```
UseDevelopmentStorage=true
```

and

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;
TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;
QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;
```

Everything is working properly in production environments, the issue is only related to the emulated service and specifically for the queues (emulated blobs are working as expected).

Any idea?

Comment: What is the version of SDK you’re using?

Comment: @GauravMantri "azure-storage": "^2.8.1"

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your error after testing your code with SDK 2.8.1.

I get detailed log from console by using `queueSvc.logger.level = azure.Logger.LogLevels.DEBUG;`.
The request uri generated by this method is `https://devstoreaccount1.queue.core.windows.net:443/myqueue/messages`, which is used to access storage account online called devstoreaccount1.

To access storage emulator:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var devStoreCreds = azure.generateDevelopmentStorageCredentials();
var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService(devStoreCreds);
```