# How to connect to Development Azure Storage (local) with the new NodeJS @azure/storage-queue library?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

In the Old : https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage
there is a way to simply connect to the local Azure Store Emulator, example:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var queueSvc = azure.createQueueService("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

I am unable to find a substitute or example for https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-queue

Comment: Did this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700569/azure-storage-emulator-with-nodejs-createqueueservice-error) help you?

Comment: @Frank Gong , that was for old 'azure-storage' npm. I provided the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { QueueServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-queue");

const queueServiceClient = QueueServiceClient.fromConnectionString("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");    
const queueClient = queueServiceClient.getQueueClient("<your queue name>");

// do your stuffs
```